# Can't install "laravel-apidoc-generator" due to "Conclusion: remove doctrine/inflector 2.0.3"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, api-doc

I'm trying to install laravel-apidoc-generator (https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator) in my latest Lumen REST API.

This is my Lumen version: `Lumen (8.0.1) (Laravel Components ^8.0)`
This is my PHP version: `PHP 7.3.22`.

When I'm trying to install the apidoc-generator, I'm getting the following error message.
This is what I'm using to install: `composer require mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator`

> Problem 1 - Conclusion: don't install mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 4.8.2 - Conclusion: don't install mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 4.8.1 - Conclusion: don't install mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 4.8.0 - Conclusion: remove doctrine/inflector 2.0.3 - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/inflector 2.0.3 - illuminate/console 5.7.17 requires illuminate/support 5.7.* -> satisfiable by il.......

And also after this error, I can see this error too:

> - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/console v8.11.2|install illuminate/console 5.7.17|install illuminate/console 5.7.18|install illuminate/console 5.7.19|install illuminate/console 5.7.x-dev|install illuminate/console 5.8.x-dev|install illuminate/console v5.7.0|install illuminate/console v5.7.1|install illuminate/console v5.7.10|install illuminate/console v5.7.11|install illuminate/console v5.7.15|install illuminate/console v5.7.2|install illuminate/console v5.7.20|install illuminate/console v5.7.21|install illuminate/console v5.7.22|install illuminate/console v5.7.23|install illuminate/console v5.7.26|install illuminate/console v5.7.27|install illuminate/console v5.7.28|install illuminate/console v5.7.3|install illuminate/console v5.7.4|install illuminate/console v5.7.5|install illuminate/console v5.7.6|install illuminate/console v5.7.7|install illuminate/console v5.7.8|install illuminate/console v5.7.9|install illuminate/console v5.8.0|install illuminate/console v5.8.11|install illuminate/console v5.8.12|install illuminate/console v5.8.14|install illuminate/console v5.8.15|install illuminate/console v5.8.17|install illuminate/console v5.8.18|install illuminate/console v5.8.19|install illuminate/console v5.8.2|install illuminate/console v5.8.20|install illuminate/console v5.8.22|install illuminate/console v5.8.24|install illuminate/console v5.8.27|install illuminate/console v5.8.28|install illuminate/console v5.8.29|install illuminate/console v5.8.3|install illuminate/console v5.8.30|install illuminate/console v5.8.31|install illuminate/console v5.8.32|install illuminate/console v5.8.33|install illuminate/console v5.8.34|install illuminate/console v5.8.35|install illuminate/console v5.8.36|install illuminate/console v5.8.4|install illuminate/console v5.8.8|install illuminate/console v5.8.9.......

So this is what I have tried so far.

1. I tried to install a lower version of doctrine.  `composer require doctrine/inflector:1.4.0`

It gives me following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
> - Conclusion: don't install mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 4.8.2
> - Conclusion: don't install mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 4.8.1
> - Conclusion: don't install mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 4.8.0
> - Conclusion: remove illuminate/console v8.11.2
> - Installation request for mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator ^4.8 -> satisfiable by mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator[4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.2, v4.x-dev].
> - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/console v8.11.2
> - mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator v4.x-dev requires illuminate/console ^5.7|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.

2. I cleared all cache and tested again. Same error.

Is this a common error with Laravel/Lumen?
How to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove composer.lock and reinstall composer package again.

Comment: @FaridVatani Already did and the same error.

Comment: did you test in laravel 7? and try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @FaridVatani No I have no permission to change the Laravel version :-(

Comment: You try to install in this way `composer require mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator` But you didn't get an answer, right? and if its possible share your composer code

Comment: Full error message would probably help. But if you read it, it will tell you that some package is trying to install version X when your other packages need version Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [on the packagist site for that package](https://packagist.org/packages/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator), the package is not compatible with Laravel 8. And as you can read in [their issue tracker](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator/issues/750), the maintainers recommend to use [`knuckleswtf/scribe`](https://github.com/knuckleswtf/scribe) instead

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I will check everything again and will get back to you. :-)